# Talend Open Studio for Big Data adding a custom column in the schema

Tags: schema, bigdata, talend

I am using Talend Open Studio for Big Data and I need to somehow add new columns to the schema of any component that i'm using. Right now I have: Column, Key, Type, Nullable, Date Pattern, Precision, Default, Comment. I would like to add new columns that behave like Nullable (you have a checkbox) and they could be called like "searchable" or "indexable". I tried looking everywhere but 
it seems that nobody had this problem. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would mean changing/extending the way schemas are implemented in Talend Open Studio.  It is possible, but would be a huge effort.  There is no configuration option or other way to simply add columns to a schema definition without changing the product itself.

Try representing your additional columns as data, not as a schema definition.